# sql deleat from one table with compare data another table both don't have PK,FK relation

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two table name tblstu and tblmark tblstu have 3 records with respective pk(1,2,3) same record in tblmark but tblmark have 3 extra record which is not found in tblstu who can i deleat the non matching record from tblmark where there is no relation of p.k and f.k in both tables

Comment: Why both MySQL and SQL Server tags? Are both products involved here?

Comment: `delete m from tblmark  m join tblstu s on m.id <> s.id`

Comment: Does that work with both MySQL and SQL Server?

Comment: ifyouregoingtoomitpunctuationyoumightaswellomitspacestoo

Comment: yes both are involve
we are working on a project first develop in php and after that mapp the project in .net

Comment: So you want a DELETE that works with both products then? (General advise, try to stick to ANSI SQL compliant code if possible, because both those products have some own ways of doing stuff.)

Answer (score 0):

ANSI SQL answer:

```
delete from tblmark where id not IN (select id from tblstu)
```

If tblstu.id is nullable, adjust to:

```
delete from tblmark where id not IN (select id from tblstu where id is not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM tblmark
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tblstu
                  WHERE tblmark.PK = tblstu.PK)
```